# nginx and gunicorn number of workers

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, worker

we now that both gunicorn and nginx has wokers.

When using nginx+gunicorn to deploy a django app on a vps.

What is the best value for number of workers in gunicorn and nginx? should they be equal? or with any special ratio?

I've followed the formula : n_workers = 2*cpu_cores + 1 for both. but my server load became very high and the vps provider suspended my vps.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that your workers should really vary on how much CPU Cores you have since that is where the threading starts. Like right now I have an 8 core server which means that I also have 8 workers to evenly distribute the workload for my Django App, that really works.

Comment: my question is the number of workers that i use for gunicorn should be equal to nginx or what?

Comment: I think the best value would be something that is equal to the number of cores that you have.